# How do I revert changes I made with Colab on Github?

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I accidently pushed changes I made to my python Colab project into a C# project I have on Github instead of the python project where I usually store my Colab project. How do I revert the changes? Can I just delete the file on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the file on Github by using the web interface. Then I pulled from github and then I just pushed it again to github without doing any changes

Answer (score 0):

you can always rollback using git system.

1. Know what is the commit hash you were safe until
2. checkout that commit into a branch.
3. merge that new branch with master.

alternatively you can use `revert` command in git

`git revert <commit hash>`